# Getting multiple http response codes using cURL?

Tags: php, curl, http-response-codes

Please take a look at this sample code:

```
function http_response($url)
{
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $head = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        echo $httpCode ;
}
```

this code will print the httpCode of the given url. I have couple of questions:

1. Can I get rid of some setopt() lines here and still getting httpCode?
2. What about if I want to check multiple urls at the same time? Can I modify the code to do that?
3. Can I do the same functionality in a simpler way using libraries different than cURL?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should be able to remove `CURLOPT_HEADER` and `CURLOPT_NOBODY` and still get the same result.
- You could do that like this:

  ```
  $urls = array(
      'http://google.com',
      'http://facebook.com'
  );

  $status = array();

  foreach($urls as $url){
      $status[$url] = http_response($url);
  }
  ```

  Try `print_r($status);` after this and you'll see the result.
- You could do this with `file_get_contents` and `$http_response_header`, to learn more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php I would however recommend using cURL anyway.

Comment: Thanks Rose. Regarding the second point, I want to finish checking multiple urls in parallel to save time. I think the loop approach is not good here because it will process the urls one after the other. Any ideas?

Comment: You could spawn multiple processes and let them run in parallel.

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php you wouldn't save that much time actually but it could be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

*2. to check multiple urls you have to use this function in a loop, in any programming language 1 response from a server = 1 connection to that server. If you want to use 1 function to get responses from multiple servers you can always pass an array to the function and do the loop inside the function

*3. you can try this way:

```
function get_contents() {
  file_get_contents("http://example.com");
  var_dump($http_response_header);
}


get_contents();
```